# Sorting a dictionary by value with linq in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort a dictionary by value with LINQ but I can't figure how the ToDictionary() method works.

All the examples I can find are in c#.

here's my code

```
Dim f As Dictionary(Of String, String) =  (From value In projectDescriptions.Values
                                           Order By value Ascending
                                           Select value).ToDictionary(???)
```

**UPDATE**

Finally, I just realized that was stupid. Sorry

I did a list (of keyValuePair(of string,string))

And to sort my list, I do

```
mylist.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Value).ToList()
```

hope it will help someone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you didn't find an example of this, but check [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx#Y0). Something like the following should work in VB.

```
'not sure what the key is, but use whichever property you'd like
Dim f As Dictionary(Of String, String) =  
      (From value In projectDescriptions.Values
      Order By value Ascending
      Select value).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key)
```

But if you store a sorted enumerator in a dictionary again, it becomes **unsorted**, that's a property of a dictionary or map in general and is precisely why dictionaries are so fast and popular. If you need it sorted, perhaps you want to use [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) instead?

Comment: You are right, I just realized how stupid my question is. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Can your just use [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)?

---

Also in C# what you want to achieve would look like the following:

```cs
// enumerate dic itself, not just dic.Values
(from p in dic
orderby p.Value ascending
select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Key, p.Value)
 // or new { Key = p.Key, Value = p.Value })
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

what is the same to

```cs
dic.OrderBy(p => p.Value).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
                   // or .ToDictionary(p => p.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary does not make any guarantees about the order of the entries. I suggest You select the entries and convert it to a List of those KeyValuePairs:

```
Dim f = projectDescriptions.OrderBy(Function(p) p.Value).ToList()
```

**Update:** If you look at [the documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx), you will find that it explicitly states that "The order in which the items are returned is undefined". So really. Do *not* expect a Dictionary to be ordered.

Comment: You will get `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` not `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? Botz is right, there is no guarantee about the order of a Dictionary, so it doesn't make sense to sort a dictionary by value.

Comment: @abatishchev isn't that exactly what he suggests? see Botz's text.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Yes, order is not guaranteed. But you can guarantee it by sorting. Before new insertion I think order will remain the same.

Comment: @abatishchev: Yes it might work but it's not how dictionaries are meant to be used. If you want to iterate items in some order, than what's the point of using a dictionary? A list will suffice.

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Iterating a dictionary is not a good idea at all, then.

Comment: Internally, the items in a dictionary are ordered by some hash of the key. That's how hashtables work. Also, look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx MSDN says: "**The order in which the items are returned is undefined.**"

Comment: -1 Your code failed to compile in Visual Studio 2010. VS said 'Declaration expected'

Comment: @Down: That's C# not VB.NET, obviously

Comment: @Down: Someone who knows VB should notice the difference but still get the point. Anyway, converted it to VB now.